# "Cannot find name 'ServiceWorkerRegistration'" error when creating a firebase cloud function using Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm receiving the following error (photo below) when I deploy my cloud function with the module `firebase` installed. [image: Error when trying to deploy my cloud functions]

I've tried installing `@types/firebase` and `firebase` and receive the same error.  I'm pretty sure this error has something to do with this module because when both `firebase` and `@types/firebase` are uninstalled, the function deploys properly.

Also, the cloud functions are not calling this module yet so I don't think the error is in the function.  I've provided the code for my `package.json` file and `ts.config` file.  Any idea why I'm getting this error and how I can import modules without getting this error?  Let me know if there's another file worth reviewing.  Thank you.

## ./package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dom": "0.0.3",
    "expo-server-sdk": "^2.4.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.3",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "private": true
}
```

## ./tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "allowJs": true,
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to be using `firebase` inside a Cloud Function, but rather [firebase-admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If like me you actually need to use the client firebase module inside a cloud function, the problem, along with a work-around, is described in [#880](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/880#issuecomment-401896926):

> A workaround is to add `"dom"` to the `"lib"` compiler option in your `tsconfig.json`
>
> Our packages assume that DOM types exist. The problem is that importing `firebase/app` imports typings of all packages.
>
> Some of our packages (like Messaging) only work in the browser. These packages (or their types) should not be imported in a Node environment.

**Edit: here is a safer answer that was posted in the issue thread**

> The suggested/promoted workaround here of adding "dom" to compilerOptions.lib is NOT safe. That would be telling the compiler that any and all dom type references are valid in my code, which is clearly not the case since Node.js is not a browser environment. If this library is meant to be used as a Node.js TypeScript library, then it should not depend on ambient dom-specific type definitions. A safer workaround for TypeScript 3.0 users is to import firebase as follows:

```js
/// <reference lib="dom" />
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

> That first line is a "triple-slash lib directive" (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) first available in TypeScript 3.0. It's like adding dom to compilerOptions.lib but only for that one file. Note that the triple-slash directive must appear before any statements or it gets interpreted as just a normal comment.

Comment: In my case, I could fix the issue by not importing anything from `"firebase/app"` (e.g. I changed `import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';` to `import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';`)

Comment: This answer is very close, but a better solution (and reasoning) is this comment further down on #880

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/880#issuecomment-483423711

Comment: The safer answer is actually not safe because the included definition is not scoped to only that included file. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/880#issuecomment-577523198.

Answer (score 13):

I've run into this problem several times in the past. You can try adding the following to your tsconfig.json:

### tsconfig.json:

```
  "files": [
    "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
```

So your complete tsconfig.json should look as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "files": [
    "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank you this fixed it, but can you tell me why please??

Answer (score -1):

Michael's comment is correct so flagging this as answered.  I was using `firebase`, but should have been using `firebase-admin`.

Comment: I don't agree with this. The "firebase" package is the only way you can send password reset emails from Cloud functions for example.

Comment: this is not a correct answer for this question. With firebase-admin SDK you can't send the default reset password you can just get the url link and then you need to send it on your own.

Comment: I'm upvoting this. In my case, I have a project with `firebase` installed on a root package, and `firebase-admin` installed on the /functions package. In one of my files, I was importing `firebase` to get a certain type, which is incorrect because `firebase` uses DOM libs. I should have been importing from `firebase-admin` instead.